# Maintain Facebook Session

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook

I have a php application where the user is authenticated using facebook php library (oAuth), now once the user is logged in to my site I want to enable Share with friends feature which is availabe at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ the javascript example

The issue is when I am trying to do so, I have to relogin again and then only I am able to use this invite feature.

Can any one please tell me how I can fix this, so that I do not have to relogin again

Comment: When you authenticate user ask for publish permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this code to authenticate the user which I mention in the question here. Let me know if this helps

[How to redirect after authorizing to the canvas page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9399736/how-to-redirect-after-authorizing-to-the-canvas-page)